# Blocks and Objects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, function, lambda, objective-c-blocks

I've started learning how to use blocks/functions/lambda in Objective-C. But I can't get it to work with Objects. Probably I'm missing some pointer, but it's not working however I do.
This is my code for the moment:

```
MyEventArgs (^skapaEventArg)(Operation); 
skapaEventArg = ^(Operation a) { return *[[MyEventArgs alloc] initWithOperation:a]; };
MyEventArgs *a = skapaEventArg(Add);
```

But I get the error that this pic shows:

[image]

If I do

```
MyEventArgs a = skapaEventArg(Add);
```

to put it on the stack, Xcode gives me the usual "Interface cannot be statically allocated"-error

How do I get this simple code to work, using blocks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

```
MyEventArgs *(^skapaEventArg)(Operation); 
skapaEventArg = ^(Operation a) { return [[MyEventArgs alloc] initWithOperation:a]; };
MyEventArgs *a = skapaEventArg(Add);
```

Note the `*` in the first line, and the lack of it in the second line.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. I knew there was something wrong with my pointers.
This was one of those combinations I didn't try. 
But I understand why. The return must be specified to be a pointer in the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

```
return *[[MyEventArgs alloc] initWithOperation:a];
```

I think you get "incompatible type" error because you return dereferenced pointer.